# Wamp and Orange Icon

Tags: wamp

So I seem to have the common problem of the orange icon with regards to Wamp on Windows 7. However Skype and TeamViwer are not running. I have also changed my port Number to 8888 and still no change. I've stopped and started all service. but no change at all . Does anybody have any other suggestions?

Update. Restarted my laptop and now the Icon wont change from red?

Comment: any changes in php.ini ?? problem is in the fresh install or an existing one ??

Comment: No Changes to php.ini. I had to wipe, my previous install due to adding password to root. So I deleted all files and did a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the apache error log and the mysql error log for error messages.

If nothing is there then look in Windows event viewer for error messages from Apache and/or Mysql. This should give you a clue to your problem.

If you still cannot solve it from these error messages, post a question on [the wampserver forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2)

and I can offer to connect via teamViewer and troubleshhot your issue

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but its probably MySQL conflict with Windows.

```
Open Windows Services. 
("Windows Button"--> Type "services"--> Hit "Enter".)
In "Services" window scroll down to MySQL instance, right click and choose stop.
```

Now restart all services on wamp.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On wamp 2.4, I clicked on wamp icon-apache-services:

1. test port 80, was available.
2. install service.
3. start service, the icon went green.